# Expresso Store - display entries based on an availability

Tags: expresso-store, channel-entries, entries, sort

The items (products) come up in alpha order currently. Is there a way to push all of the “Not in Stock” items to the end of the list when displaying entries?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there will be a way to do it without a custom query. Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT entry_id 
FROM exp_store_stock
WHERE track_stock = '1'
ORDER BY stock_level DESC
```

One quick and easy way to use a custom query in place of a channel:entries tag is to use the [Channel Query module](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/channel-query). This template code works and should be a good starting point:

```
{exp:channel_query 
    sql="SELECT entry_id 
      FROM exp_store_stock
      WHERE track_stock = '1'
      ORDER BY stock_level DESC"
    parse="inward"
}
    {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}"}
        {title}: {total_stock}
    {/exp:store:product}
{/exp:channel_query}
```

*(Tested with Store 2.3.1 and EE 2.9.0)*

Comment: This is what I though from the beginning that it will require custom query. Channel Query module should help a lot. Thanks!